# Can't install Katoolin on slax OS

Tags: kali-linux

I've tried to install Katoolin on Slax OS and it doesn't seem to work. I've searched the internet and found no answers.
So my question is that is Katoolin available in Slax OS?
If so please help me to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Katoolin has been known to break the host OS in various ways. Sometimes it changes the name of the host OS from its original name to Kali Linux. The [LionSec Katoolin GitHub](https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin) webpage clearly warns Katoolin users to be careful when updating software.

> Before updating your system, please remove all Kali-linux repositories to avoid any kind of problem.

All kinds of package management problems can occur if you don't do this.

Two alternatives to Katoolin are running running Kali Linux from a live Kali Linux USB or as a single or dual boot full installation on your hard drive.